# Count min value between two columns for product_id [Pandas]

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to count instances where date for `purchaseDateStoreA` < `purchaseDateStoreB` and vice versa

Main DF

```
product_id    purchaseDateStoreA   purchaseDateStoreB  month
34935              2019-01-01        2019-01-03        Jan-2019
64545              2019-02-01        2019-02-02        Feb-2019
35556              2019-01-17        2019-01-16        Jan-2019
```

Desired output

```
first_arrival_timestamp_storeA
Jan-2019: 1
Feb-2019: 1

first_arrival_timestamp_storeB
Jan-2019: 1
```

This is what I have tried so far for storeA only:

```
first_arrivals = df.assign(first_arrival_timestamp_storeA = df.groupby("product_id")["purchaseDateStoreA"].transform("min")).\
   query("purchaseDateStoreA == first_arrival_timestamp_storeA")
pd.pivot_table(first_arrivals, aggfunc="count", values=["product_id"])
```

Comment: Why is `first_arrival_timestamp_storeA: 3` ? Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: sorry this was a mistake it should be 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need compare values, then counts by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and rename index by dictionary:

```
df['purchaseDateStoreA'] = pd.to_datetime(df['purchaseDateStoreA'])
df['purchaseDateStoreB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['purchaseDateStoreB'])

d = {True:'purchaseDateStoreA', False:'purchaseDateStoreB'}
df = (df['purchaseDateStoreA'] < df['purchaseDateStoreB']).value_counts().rename(d)
print (df)
purchaseDateStoreA    2
purchaseDateStoreB    1
dtype: int64
```

EDIT:

```
df['purchaseDateStoreA'] = pd.to_datetime(df['purchaseDateStoreA'])
df['purchaseDateStoreB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['purchaseDateStoreB'])

d = {True:'purchaseDateStoreA', False:'purchaseDateStoreB'}

new = (df['purchaseDateStoreA'] < df['purchaseDateStoreB']).map(d)

df = df.groupby(['month', new.rename('stores')]).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
      month              stores  count
0  Feb-2019  purchaseDateStoreA      1
1  Jan-2019  purchaseDateStoreA      1
2  Jan-2019  purchaseDateStoreB      1
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I groupby date here? i.e. showing the results grouped by the respective day

Comment: @user12625679 - Can you change data sample? Because now sample data is not [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so not easy undersyand how data are grouped.

Comment: @user12625679 - Also how looks expected output? Now there is no date. Please change it.

Comment: apologies just made the change

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, two filter criteria; two results.  I used a dict for results

```
data = '''product_id    purchaseDateStoreA   purchaseDateStoreB
34935              2019-01-01        2019-01-03
64545              2019-02-01        2019-02-02
35556              2019-01-17        2019-01-16'''
da = [[i for i in re.split("[ ][ ]+", l)] for l in data.split("\n")]
df = pd.DataFrame(da[1:], columns=da[0])
df.purchaseDateStoreA = pd.to_datetime(df.purchaseDateStoreA)
df.purchaseDateStoreB = pd.to_datetime(df.purchaseDateStoreB)
{"first_arrival_timestamp_storeA":df[df.purchaseDateStoreA < df.purchaseDateStoreB]["product_id"].count(),
"first_arrival_timestamp_storeB":df[df.purchaseDateStoreB < df.purchaseDateStoreA]["product_id"].count()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a column and attribute it with the the store names conditionally. You can use `np.where( if df.purchaseDateStoreA<df.purchaseDateStoreB, then;purchaseDateStoreA, otherwise;purchaseDateStoreB)`. Then `value_counts()` the stores

```
 import numpy as np
df.assign(holding=np.where(df.purchaseDateStoreA<df.purchaseDateStoreB,\
                           'purchaseDateStoreA','purchaseDateStoreB'))
df.holding.value_counts()



  purchaseDateStoreA    2
  purchaseDateStoreB    1
Name: holding, dtype: int64
```